# Is there something like ParameterInfo Class for c function in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to load C or `mfc` library at run-time. So, I use `WIN32Api` for load library and can get function pointer. But I don't know parameter type that is needed to function call because C or `mfc` library was changed every process.

How do I do it?

Comment: If you have a header file for the library, the information will be in there.

Comment: If you have the header file you can use [swig](http://www.swig.org/) to generated a wrapper C# library that keep up to date

Comment: Thank you. But i don't have header file because these are commercial libraries such as electronic scale, zebra printer, etc.